# How to execute an asynchronous command in vim from bash and quit vim after the command has completed?

Tags: bash, neovim

I could come up with a bash script that installs an LSP server plugin:

```
if [ ! -d $HOME/.local/share/nvim/lsp_servers/jdtls/ ]; then    
  printf "\nInstalling the Java LSP server"    
  mkdir -p ~/.local/share/nvim/lsp-servers/    
  nvim -c "LspInstall jdtls"
fi
```

But then the script never returns and the vim editor stays open.

I tried adding the quit commands but then it quits before installing the LSP server, as the installation is asynchronous:

```
nvim -c "LspInstall jdtls | q | q"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run the installation in blocking mode using the `--sync` option, which is there for exactly this purpose, scripting:

```bash
nvim -c "LspInstall --sync jdtls | q"
#                   ^^^^^^
```

Perhaps you need the extra `| q` at the end and `:` before `LspInstall`. Unfortunately, I can't test it myself.

Comment: I wanted to post my own answer `nvim --headless -c "LspInstall --sync jdtls" -c q` that I just found out when rtfm `:h nvim-lsp-installer-quickstart`

Comment: @Stephane Oh :-) That looks like a more precise answer than mine so please go ahead and add it. I think your answer will do future readers more good than mine.

Comment: @You reached out and this with a proper, correct and working answer !